# What species is on the cover of Fornax?

Tags: cover-art, mass-effect

I don't recognize this from any of the games. It looks *vaguely* like a rachni, but I strongly doubt it is. Is it ever confirmed that it *is* a rachni, or is there another species I'm not thinking of that more closely resembles it?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: Hanar]

It's a Hanar on its back in the Fornax lounge. Note the coloration and similar shapes.

The Hanar are a species resembling Earth's jellyfish and are one of the few non-bipedal Citadel races. Hanar are known for their intense politeness when speaking, and their strong religious beliefs regarding the Protheans, whom they refer to as "the Enkindlers".

Comment: Wow. I don't think I ever would have thought a Hanar could be in that position. Now that you mention it, I do see the similarity, particularly in the coloration and shapes at the "nose", "tail", and where the tentacles join the body. Good spot!

Comment: @Iszi It may not be a "natural" position for a Hanar, the equivalent of a pin-up girl bending into a provocative but impractical pose.  :P

Comment: @Iszi Putting a Hanar on the cover makes for easy tentacle jokes.